# NSPredicate acting strange in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I feel as if this should be very simple, but it's behaving strangely.

I have 3 entities, with a relationship as such

Entity A <-->> Entity B <<--> Entity C

I have an NSFetchedResults controller and I'm trying to filter the results of Entity A using the following predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE entityB.entityC == %@", self.entityC];
```

When I try and run the app, the output shows no results. I can alter the predicate slightly to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entityB.entityC == %@", self.entityC];
```

And it shows me only the results that I want it to filter out.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want a [SUBQUERY](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#jumpTo_16) expression:

```
@"SUBQUERY(entityB, $x, $x.entityC == %@).@count == 0"
```

though, it may work to do:

```
@"NOT (ANY entityB.entityC == %@)"
```

(note: I haven't tested the second option)

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully (The first option). I had tested the formatting in the second example before, but it didn't seem to work out. I never came across SUBQUERY in the documentation, I will have to do some further reading to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: @Scott L., unfortunately the SUBQUERY expression documentation is a little bit scattered. You should always file bug reports (http://bugreport.apple.com) or submit feedback at the bottom of the dev center pages for documentation failings such as this. The engineers are quite responsive. Good luck with your work.