# Core Data: fetch request for fetching entities in a one-many-one relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Say I have 3 entities `Grandparent`, `Parent`, and `Child`.

`Grandparent - Parent` is a one to many relationship

`Parent - Child` is a many to one relationship

`Child` has an `age` attribute

My goal is to get all `Child` entities of `Parent` where `Parent.grandparent` is a certain `Grandparent`. In addition, I'd like to sort the fetched results by `age`. I know I can do this in multiple steps, but my question is: how can I accomplish this in a single fetch request?

**Edit**: Perhaps this diagram will be a bit clearer than the description above.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lucky and found this answer
[NSPredicate acting strange in NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580875/nspredicate-acting-strange-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

The question was worded differently, which is why it took awhile for me to find it. Basically, the predicate I'm looking for is of the following format:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(parent, $x, $x.grandparent == %@).@count != 0", grandParent];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed variable and relationship names, change those to whatever you named them in your code and model.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent.grandparent == %@", grandParentObject];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES]];
```

This should work. I'm used to code completion and I didn't type this in Xcode, so the method names may be off a little, but you get the idea.

Comment: Do you get anything if you leave the predicate out? If so, check your grandParentObject and make sure it's part of at least one Child's Parent object.

Comment: Leaving the predicate out, I did get something. Do you think the problem has something to do with there being an NSSet of Parent objects to the Child? (Child has a one to many relationship with Parent)

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that. So a child can have many parents, but a parent can only have one child, correct?